# List of all suspended list workflows using javascript JSOM or REST api

Tags: workflow, search, rest, jsom

I am trying to get the list of all workflows in Suspended state

I looked up in google and the max that I can get is the list of workflows that are enabled in one list

```
_api/SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowSubscriptionService.Current/EnumerateSubscriptionsByList('guid in here')
```

I also tried modifying the parameters in the workflow.aspx URL. I tried removing the ID parameter etc, but nothing worked

```
_layouts/15/workflow.aspx?List={DJKD33-L7S2-93J3-90B7-L5G0FA73E562}&Source=/workflows/Lists/List Name&ID=596&ShowAll=1
```

I am able to see the status of all workflows in the site from this  url

```
_layouts/15/workflowservicehealth.aspx
```

But there is not option to see the list of suspended or terminated workflows.

Is there a way to list of all suspended workflows (list workflows) using REST api/ Search API or Javascript(JSOM) ? or are there any urls?

Answer (score 1):

May not be pretty, but this is what I put together to alert me when workflows are suspended. Replace these with your values: {SP_SITE_URL},{LIST_NAMEX},{EMAIL},{smtpSERVER} 
Now I'm trying to find out how to terminate these from REST.

```
clear-host


    $spSiteUrl = "{SP_SITE_URL}"

    $lists = @('{LIST_NAME1}','{LIST_NAME2}','{LIST_NAME1}')




    ############################################################################################################################################
    #Get Form Digest
    ############################################################################################################################################
    function GetRestFormDigest {
        if (((Get-Date) -gt $spDigestExpires) -or (!$spFormDigest)) {
            $hHeaders = @{
                "accept" = "application/json;odata=verbose"
            }

            $spRESTUrl = $spSiteUrl + "/_api/contextinfo"
            $spRESTResults = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $spRESTUrl -UseDefaultCredentials -Method POST -Headers $hHeaders

            $global:spDigestTimeout = $spRESTResults.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestTimeoutSeconds
            $global:spFormDigest = $spRESTResults.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue

            $global:spDigestExpires = (Get-Date).AddSeconds($spDigestTimeout - 1)
        }
    }

    ############################################################################################################################################
    #Get List ID
    ############################################################################################################################################
    function GetListID ($spListName){
        $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

        $spRESTUrl = $spSiteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + $spListName + "')/"

        $spRESTResults = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $spRESTUrl -UseDefaultCredentials -Method GET -Headers $hHeaders

        $spListItemEntityTypeFullName = $spRESTResults.d.ListItemEntityTypeFullName
        $spListID = $spRESTResults.d.id

        $spRESTUrl += "items"

        $spListItemRTN = @{}
        $spResults = @{}
        $rResult = @{}

        $spRESTResults = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $spRESTUrl -UseDefaultCredentials -Method GET -Headers $hHeaders

        $spRESTResultsCorrected = $spRESTResults -creplace '"Id":', '"fake_id":'

        $spJSONResults = $spRESTResultsCorrected  | ConvertFrom-Json
        $spListItems = $spJSONResults.d.results

        while ($spJSONResults.d.__next) {
            $spRESTResults = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $spJSONResults.d.__next -UseDefaultCredentials -Method GET -Headers $hHeaders
            $spRESTResultsCorrected = $spRESTResults -creplace '"Id":', '"fake_id":'
            $spJSONResults = $spRESTResultsCorrected  | ConvertFrom-Json
            $spListItems += $spJSONResults.d.results
        }

        GetRestFormDigest
        $hHeaders = @{
            "accept" = "application/json;odata=verbose";
            "content-type" = "application/json;odata=verbose";
            "content-Length" = $bBody.Length;
            "X-RequestDigest" = $spFormDigest;
            "X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED" = "f";
            "Host" = "{SP_HOST}
        }
        write-host $spListName  -BackgroundColor darkyellow
        write-host $spListItems.Count "List Items"
        write-host "---"
        write-host "ItemId - RTN - Status - Created - Updated"
        $suspended = 0
        $c = 0 
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $spListItems.Count; $i++) {
            $c++; write-progress 'List Items' -PercentComplete ($c / $spListItems.Count * 100)

            $spWorkflows = [ordered]@{}
            $spListItemID =  $spListItems[$i].id

            $spRESTUrl = $spSiteUrl + "/_api/SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowInstanceService.Current/EnumerateInstancesForListItem(listId='"+$spListID+"',itemId='"+$spListItemID+"')"
            $spRESTResults = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $spRESTUrl -UseDefaultCredentials -Method POST -Headers $hHeaders -Body $bBody -OutVariable resp

            $spJSONResults = $spRESTResultsCorrected  | ConvertFrom-Json
            $spListItems = $spJSONResults.d.results

            $spWorkflowInstances = $spRESTResults.d.results
            $oldestDate = (get-date 1900-01-01)
            $oldestKey = $null

            for ($w = 0; $w -lt $spWorkflowInstances.Count; $w++) {
                $spListItemID =  $spListItems[$w].id

                if($spWorkflowInstances[$w].Status -eq 2){
                    $suspended++
                    switch ( $spWorkflowInstances[$w].Status )
                    {
                        2 { $result = 'Suspended'; $color='red' }
                        5 { $result = 'Terminated'; $color=$null }
                        6 { $result = 'Completed'; $color=$null  }
                        default { $result = $spWorkflowInstances[$w].Status; $color=$null }
                    }
                if($color){
                write-host $spListItems[$i].id "-" $spListItems[$i].RTN "-" $spWorkflowInstances[$w].Status "=" $result "-" $spWorkflowInstances[$w].InstanceCreated " - " $spWorkflowInstances[$w].LastUpdated -BackgroundColor $color
                }else {
                write-host $spListItems[$i].id "-" $spListItems[$i].RTN "-" $spWorkflowInstances[$w].Status "=" $result "-" $spWorkflowInstances[$w].InstanceCreated " - " $spWorkflowInstances[$w].LastUpdated
                }
                    }
                if((get-date $oldestDate) -lt (get-date $spWorkflowInstances[$w].LastUpdated)){
                    $oldestDate = $spWorkflowInstances[$w].LastUpdated
                    $oldestKey = $w
                }
            }
        }
        write-progress 'List Items' -Completed
        write-host $suspended "Suspended Workflows" -BackgroundColor darkyellow
        write-host ""
        write-host ""
    }

#
#===========================================================================================================================================
#Main
#===========================================================================================================================================
#
$hHeaders = @{
    "accept" = "application/json;odata=verbose"
}

$logfile = "{PATH}"+$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name+"_"+(Get-Date).tostring("yyyy-MM-dd")+"_log.txt"

Start-Transcript -path $logfile

foreach($list in $lists){GetListID $list }

Stop-Transcript

$regexScript = '(\d+) Suspended Workflows'

foreach($line in Get-Content -Path $logfile){
    if($line -match $regexScript){
        $val = [regex]::Match($line,$regexScript).captures.groups[1].value
        #write-host $val
        if($val -ne 0){
            $Date = Get-Date
            $Body = @()
            $Body += $Date
            $Body += "<BR>Check Script Logs:<BR>"
            $Body += "Ran by: "+([Environment]::UserDomainName + "\" + [Environment]::UserName)+"<br>"

            foreach($key in $err.keys){
                if($err[$key] -match 'Script\: '){
                    $Body += "<p><b>"+[STRING]$err[$key]+"</b><BR>"
                }
                else{
                $Body += [STRING]$err[$key]+"<br>"
                }
            }

            $Body = [STRING]$Body

            Send-MailMessage -BodyAsHtml -From {EMAIL} -To {EMAIL} -Subject "Suspended Workflows" -SmtpServer {smtpSERVER} -Body $Body -Attachments $logfile


            break
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Congrats on your first answer, upvoted it. Good luck with SO